# Wait for triggered DAG

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have one control dag which triggers two other dags. The two dags should run sequentially and not in parallel. 
I tried solving the problem like this:

```
TriggerDag (using BashOp) -> ExternalDagSensor -> TriggerDag (using BashOp) -> ExternalDagSensor.
```

My problem is that the triggered DAG does get a specific `execution_date` (specific down to the seconds, not 00:00 for minutes and seconds). The DagSensor now uses the `execution_time` of the control dag to poke for the dependent dag and so the sensor never gets triggered, as the dependent dag has a different `execution_time`.

My questions:

1. Is the `Trigger->Sensor->Trigger->Sensor` pattern the right way to trigger DAGs sequentially?
2. If yes: How do I get

   a) either the `execution_date` of the dependent DAG after it has been triggered by the controller DAG (can then be passed to the sensor as argument)

   or

   b) the `execution_date` of the dependent DAG to be the same as the control DAG

If possible I do not want to query the metadata database to get the execution_time of the dependent DAG run.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple options that might be a bit simpler.

1. Can you combine the DAGs into a single DAG either by merging their tasks or composing them with [SubDagOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py)?
2. If you really must have the DAGs be separate, try eliminating the control DAG, putting both DAGs on the same start_date and schedule_interval, and having the second DAG use an ExternalTasksSensor as its first task. Since the DAGs are on the same schedule, the execution_date of the dependent DAG will be the same as that of the dependee.

Comment: mh, the second one sounds like a quite elegant solution. The problem is: I want to have the chance to run the 2 dags independently, triggered using the ui. This might only be the case 1 or 2 times a month, so another idea would be to create a separate DAG for the manual runs